# Select items that do not meet conditions

Tags: sql, t-sql

There are two tables `JOB` and `WORKER`.

JOB table

- JOBID

WORKER table

- WORKERID
- JOBID (FK from JOB table)
- VACATION ('Y' or 'N')

With these two tables, I want to find a list of jobs that no workers are now assigned.
I made the following query, but it seems inefficient and verbose because of aggregate function `SUM` and `CASE WHEN`.

Any query better than this?

```
SELECT
    SUBQUERY.JOBID
FROM
(
    SELECT
        JOBID,
        SUM
        (
            CASE WHEN
                VACATION = 'N'
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END
        ) NUM_WORKERS
    FROM
        JOB
    LEFT JOIN
        WORKER
    ON
        JOB.JOBID = WORKER.JOBID
    GROUP BY
        JOB.JOBID
) SUBQUERY
WHERE
    SUBQUERY.NUM_WORKERS = 0
```

Comment: Please change your tag and add tsql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select * 
From job
Where jobid not in( select distinct jobid from worker)

Thats it.

Comment: Except the query by the OP will *also* select those jobs where all workers are on vacation, where as your query will only select those jobs with no workers assigned.

Comment: This is the list of jobs that no workers assigned. So what is your problem?

Comment: It works! VACATION flag did not mentioned on your answer but I simply added flag checking on select distinct subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here, hope it helps

```
SELECT JOBID 
FROM JOB 
WHERE JOBID NOT IN (
    SELECT j.JOBID 
    FROM JOB j 
    JOIN WORKER w ON j.JOBID = w.JOBID
    WHERE w.VACATION = 'N'
    GROUP BY j.JOBID
)
```

Sqlfiddle example: [**EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81aa3/4)

Comment: Except the query by the OP will *also* select those jobs where all workers are on vacation, where as your query will only select those jobs with no workers assigned. Your sqlFiddle should return jobs 1, 2, 3, and 4 as all workers in jobs 1, 2, and 4 are on vacation.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this:

```
SELECT j.jobid 
FROM job AS j
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT 1
        FROM worker AS w 
        WHERE w.vacation = 'N'
          AND w.jobid = j.jobid
      ) ;
```

or this:

```
SELECT j.jobid 
FROM job AS j

EXCEPT

SELECT w.jobid
FROM worker AS w 
WHERE w.vacation = 'N' ;
```